# android app crashed on second run based on cocos2dx 1.0.1 0.12.0

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I modify pariticle tests project based on tests projects in source. change Cocos2dxActivity.java files

```
public static void terminateProcess(){
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

to

```
public static void terminateProcess(){
    finish();
}
```

I Uses this changes on cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1, Activity can run second times successfully. But on cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.12.0 (even cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.13.0-beta), Activity ran successfully first times, failed on second times, success on the third time.

Code failed on new AppDelegate.

```
void Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit(
  JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz, jint   w, jint h)
{
   if (!cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getOpenGLView())
   {
  cocos2d::CCEGLView *view = &cocos2d::CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();
      view->setFrameWidthAndHeight(w, h);
      cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->setOpenGLView(view);
      //Code failed here.
      AppDelegate *pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();
      cocos2d::CCApplication::sharedApplication().run();
   }
   else
   {
      cocos2d::CCTextureCache::reloadAllTextures();
      cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->setGLDefaultValues();
   }
}
```

here is crash log

```
07-31 15:30:05.520: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(134): <CreateImage:896>: Android Image
07-31 15:30:05.520: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(134): <GetImageAttributes:1105>: RGBA_8888
07-31 15:30:05.540: V/PhoneStatusBar(435): setLightsOn(true)
07-31 15:30:05.600: D/memalloc(134): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x4239c000 size:1658880 fd:53 1000000 0
07-31 15:30:05.600: D/memalloc(803): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5cfd1000 size:1658880 offset:0 fd:81
07-31 15:30:05.610: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(803): <ConfigWindowMatch:2104>: Format RGB_565.
07-31 15:30:05.610: D/memalloc(134): ion: Allocated buffer base:0x425f0000 size:798720 fd:60 1000000 0
07-31 15:30:05.610: D/memalloc(803): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d166000 size:798720 offset:0 fd:84
07-31 15:30:05.630: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(134): <CreateImage:896>: Android Image
07-31 15:30:05.630: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(134): <GetImageAttributes:1105>: RGBA_8888
07-31 15:30:05.640: I/ActivityManager(315): Displayed com.test.benchmark/org.cocos2dx.tests.TestsDemoV1: +167ms
07-31 15:30:05.640: D/particle(803): Enter OpenCLView
07-31 15:30:05.640: D/particle(803): Enter OpenCLView 2
07-31 15:30:05.640: D/particle(803): Enter OpenCLView 3
07-31 15:30:05.650: D/particle(803): Enter OpenCLView 4
07-31 15:30:05.650: A/libc(803): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
07-31 15:30:05.660: D/memalloc(803): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c2d9000 size:1658880
07-31 15:30:05.660: D/memalloc(134): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x42f50000 size:1658880 fd:47
07-31 15:30:05.660: D/memalloc(134): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x42f50000 size:1658880
07-31 15:30:05.660: D/memalloc(803): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c56e000 size:1658880
07-31 15:30:05.990: D/memalloc(134): ion: Freeing buffer base:0x4315c000 size:1658880 fd:56
07-31 15:30:05.990: D/memalloc(134): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4315c000 size:1658880
07-31 15:30:06.000: V/AudioHardwareMSM8660(137): AudioStreamOutMSM72xx::write(0x1c918, 4800) dev = speaker_stereo_rx
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740): Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/mione_plus/mione_plus:4.0.4/IMM76D/2.7.20:user/release-keys'
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740): pid: 803, tid: 921  >>> com.ludashi.benchmark <<<
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  r0 deadbaad  r1 00000001  r2 40000000  r3 00000000
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  r4 00000000  r5 00000027  r6 00000000  r7 581adf48
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  r8 5ca51c10  r9 581adf40  10 00000008  fp 5ca51c24
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  ip 00000000  sp 5ca51b90  lr 400cd4b9  pc 400c9c18  cpsr 60000030
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  d0  3a6432736f636f63  d1  696c70704143433a
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  d2  3a3a6e6f69746163  d3  63696c7070414343
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  d8  436a000043340000  d9  43f00000000000ea
07-31 15:30:06.160: I/DEBUG(30740):  d10 0000000044138000  d11 0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d16 64656c6961662022  d17 2220656c6966203a
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d24 3f582b387b22f3c1  d25 3f6dcabc4571abc1
07-31 15:30:06.170: I/DEBUG(30740):  d26 3f30837711244472  d27 3f4375429245411f
07-31 15:30:06.170: V/AudioPolicyManager(137): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1
07-31 15:30:06.170: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(137): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
07-31 15:30:06.170: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(137): getNewDevice() selected device 0
07-31 15:30:06.170: V/AudioPolicyManager(137): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 0
07-31 15:30:06.170: V/AudioPolicyManager(137): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
07-31 15:30:06.180: I/DEBUG(30740):  d28 3f133abc51b768d7  d29 3f1420ec8fb87f66
07-31 15:30:06.180: I/DEBUG(30740):  d30 3efb2a7074bf7ad4  d31 3ff0000000000000
07-31 15:30:06.180: I/DEBUG(30740):  scr 60000012
07-31 15:30:06.360: I/DEBUG(30740):          #00  pc 00017c18  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 15:30:06.360: I/DEBUG(30740):          #01  pc 0001edb4  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2)
07-31 15:30:06.360: I/DEBUG(30740):          #02  pc 0011ff4c
```

can anybody help me about this question? I tried to look for any fixed on changelog, but got no ideas. 
thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the crash logs ?

Comment: @SaurabhVerma Thanks for reply. I have post the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Check this line: 07-31 15:30:05.650: A/libc(803): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)

trying

07-31 15:30:06.000: V/AudioHardwareMSM8660(137): AudioStreamOutMSM72xx::write(0x1c918, 4800) dev = speaker_stereo_rx
```

You have an exception. It not a compile error, you are trying to write in audio, but you have not access. Check if file is open, if file exist, etc.

Comment: I guess why this is happening is the finish() method does not kill the program but halt, and later on when onResume() called, mEGLView is looking for some resources but actually already been finished by android. so when your start your game at second time, it actually looking for the previous halt process, and find out that the process cannot been run anymore so the system kill it. This explains why the second run always fail because only the third run is a real re-start. second run only try to resume.